# "Manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened." when access a spring restful url

Tags: spring, url, internet-explorer-8

i searched stackoverflow, and there are some same error posts. but, those are all about c# clickonce application.

here is a spring restful api in my scene. it's a url .

this works well in almost all other web browsers, but no function well in ie8.

total error information is here:

> ERROR SUMMARY
>   Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>   * Activation of http://dns/path?type=cleanSomething resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>   + Exception reading manifest from http://dns/path?type=cleanSomething: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>   + Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
>   No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>   There were no warnings during this operation.

could anyone give me some advice to solve this problem, thanks a lot!